# Install drupal under subfolder

Tags: installation

I'm using a 3rd party hosting service for a Drupal 7 installation, and would like to put my Drupal site under the public_html folder like this:

```
public_html
|
|
|---->mysite
       |
       |-->includes
       |-->misc
       |-->modules
       |-->profiles
       |-->scripts
       |-->sites
```

However, I'm not sure what settings.php values I need to set, nor what if any .htaccess settings need to be changed?

Answer (score 2):

You should be fine.  You will probably need to change the

```
$base_url = 'http://my-path/subdir';
```

in your settings.php so that drupal is aware of it.  Also in your .htaccess you will see

```
RewriteBase /drupal
```

that is commented out.  Uncomment this and add your path

Comment: Thanks very much.  Showing again my newbie-ness on Drupal, do I change the .htaccess file under public_html, or public_html/mysite?

Comment: Change it under public_html/mysite